# Make dynamic SVG like Travis CI build status

Tags: javascript, ruby, svg

I'm trying to create an SVG that works much like the Travis CI build status icon.

Looking at the url:

```
https://travis-ci.org/ddavison/sublime-tabs.svg?branch=master
```

The URL points to an SVG, but the SVG seems to be able to pull information from another source, hence the "passing" or "failing" message..  How can I replicate this?

I've tried faking the browser by making it a `<script>`, and just generating an SVG, but that doesn't seem to work. It just renders XML on the page. Is it possible that Travis has a rule that parses `.svg` as some other script file?

How can I execute JavaScript before i actually render the SVG to the user?

Comment: Presumably there's a server behind that URL that's generating the data on demand.

Comment: With URL rewriting, it's possible to serve something for an URL that normally would not exist. You should look into `mod_rewrite` in apache. And btw, this can't be done with JS only like this.

Comment: @sircapsalot "like this" reffered to the linked svg's source containing no JavaScript. It is generated on the server side.

Comment: i know that you're most likely right.. when i try to plug this svg into a github readme, it doesn't actually execute the javascript

Comment: @DJDavid98 I ended up generating it Server Side.. that seemed to be the best way anyway http://github.com/ddavison/github-svg-buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out.  Per @DJDavid98 's comment, I ended up generating the image server side.

Here's an example:

[image]

I ended up using Ruby to generate it as JavaScript actually is not allowed on a GitHub Readme!

Try it yourself!  Generate some buttons for people to star/fork your repo on github:

http://githubbadges.com